# Group policy to enable windows narrator

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I was wondering if there is any way to set the windows narrator to be enabled/run at login via group policy. A few of our users are visually impaired so I wanted to make it easier for them by applying this policy to a security group for them. That way the feature will be enabled regardless of which domain machine they login to.

Not sure if it makes a difference but our environment is a mix of Win 7 and 10 machines (and a few Macs but I'm not going to worry about those).

I'd like to avoid using login scripts but if that is the only way, I can consider those too.

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remind them of the shortcut to turn on Navigator,  <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Also show them now to navigate [Settings > Ease of Access > Navigator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17180/windows-10-make-your-pc-easier-to-use). This will help them on any Windows 10 machine they are using, joined to your domain or not.

If you implement [user experience virtualization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/ue-v/uev-configuring-uev-with-group-policy-objects), Ease of Access settings are synchronized by default. A bigger project, but it also covers other accessibility features like high contrast.

The registry keys in question are probably under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Narrator\NoRoam\  I am unclear as to if toggling them is sufficient or you would also would need to run the executable.

Comment: Adding to that, Win+U is the shortcut to open Ease of access directly.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. For some reason I can't seem to find that registry path on our Win 7 machines but I guess that wont be a problem for much longer since all those systems are going to upgraded or replaced soon.